# Changing column values based on a column value and checking NaN value at other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset as shown. if column "statement" contains word "America" and if column "count_2" value is not NaN
then I want to make that value in column "count_2" as NaN and corresponding "count_1" value 1.

```
statement                                  count_1  count_2

The America is a large country             NaN      1
China is one of the large country in Asia  1        NaN
America has silicon valley                 1        Nan
America has a beautifil climate            1        NaN
Russia has a very cold temperature         NaN      1
Brazil has a tropical climate              NaN      1
America has the Google headquartter        1        NaN
```

I have tried the below code

```
for i in range(len(statement)):
    if "america" in df['blobContent'][i].lower(): 
        df.loc[df['count_2'].notnull(), ['count_1', 'count_2']] = df.loc[df['count_2'].notnull(), ['count_2', 'count_1']].values
```

I want my result as below: Thanks

```
statement                                  count_1  count_2

The America is a large country             1        NaN
China is one of the large country in Asia  1        NaN
America has silicon valley                 1        NaN
America has a beautifil climate            1        NaN
Russia has a very cold temperature         NaN      1
Brazil has a tropical climate              NaN      1
America has the Google headquartter        1        NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it without forloop using `contains`

```
m=df.statement.str.contains('America')&df.count_2.notnull()
df.loc[m,['count_1', 'count_2']]=df.loc[m,['count_2', 'count_1']].values
```